# why i am getting this error in my jdbc java code while using correct username and password?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting error in my JDBC java code as my trying to connect mysql server  but it is throwing error as `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I am using the correct password and username as it is working in some other simple code and that code runs successfully with the same username and password.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
String uname = "root";
String pass = "mynewjava";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
Statement st = con.createStatement();
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main(TimezoneDump.java:70)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: yes fallingCoder

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the password like this in the connection string :

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname?user=user&password=password");
```

So for your example data it would look like this :

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root&password=mynewjava");
```

Comment: not getting the result with, Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?user=root&password=mynewjava"); .same error